# Finding a denumerable set $X_0$ satisfying a condition.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(X,\tau)$, with $X$ an uncountable set, $x_0 \in X$ fixed, be the space with topology generated by the collection: $$\mathscr{B} = \{ \{x\} \mid x \in X \setminus \{x_0\}\} \cup \{ A \subset X \mid x_0 \in A \text{ and } X \setminus A \text{ is countable} \}.$$

Let $f: X \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. I must show that exists $X_0 \subset X$ countable such that for all $x\in X \setminus X_0$, we have $f(x) = f(x_0)$. I am given the hint that the inverse images of points in the real line are closed sets.

**Work:** the hint strongly suggests looking at: $$f^{-1}(\{f(x_0)\}) = \{x \in X \mid f(x) = f(x_0) \}.$$

My first impulse is looking at the complement $X \setminus f^{-1}(\{f(x_0)\})$. By the hint this is open, and if $x$ isn't there, we have $f(x) = f(x_0)$. But telling me that this is open is useless, because since $x_0 \not\in X\setminus f^{-1}(\{f(x_0)\})$, I only know that this set is the reunion of its points. This could be a big set. And with this in mind, I just take $X_0$ any countable subset and I'm done.

So in the end I didn't use that $f$ is continuous, so my reasoning most certainly is wrong. Any explanations? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be continuous. Since $\{A \subset X: |X \setminus A|\leq \omega \wedge x_0 \in A\}$ is a local basis for $x_0$, for each $n \geq 1$, let $A_n\subset X$ be a basic open neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $f[A_n] \subset (f(x_0)-\frac{1}{n},f(x_0)+\frac{1}{n})$ such that $X \setminus A_n$ is countable. Let $X_0=\bigcup_{n \geq 1} X \setminus A_n=X \setminus \bigcap_{n \geq 1}A_n$. $X_0$ is countable. If $x \in X \setminus X_0$, then $x \in \bigcap_{n \geq 1} A_n$, therefore, for each $n$, $f(x) \in f[A_n] \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{1}{n}$. Since $n$ is arbitrary this means $f(x)=f(x_0)$.